# Is the Windows default drag & drop behavior configurable?

Tags: windows

**Default drag & drop behavior**

- Same drive, **move**.
- Different drive, **copy**.

Is this configurable?  If so, how?

*FYI, I know you can right click, drag and drop, to get a Move/Copy context menu.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't configurable...at least not that I'm aware of.  Microsoft hasn't chosen to make it configurable via a registry setting, etc.

I cite:  http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/09/427240.aspx

I tried to google search for any updates to that to disagree with it, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Yeah.  That was what I thought.  Thanks TheCleaner.
Maybe I'll look at writing an AutoIt script or something.  I asked for a very specific purpose.